# Dynamicly change property-placeholders in maven

Tags: maven

Is it possible to change value in maven property-placeholders on build? For example I want to trim external `${version} = 20.255.2532` to `${version} = 20.255`.

Comment: Take a look at Maven 3.2.5+ http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html#Continuous_delivery_friendly_versions_MNG-5576